# Titanium ACS issue

Tags: titanium

trying to create an ACS server using Titanium Studio. Following the example of pixgrid (https://github.com/appcelerator/pixgrid/), but always get an error when trying to run locally; console output:

> [INFO]  Installing dependencies...
>
> [INFO]  Dependencies installed.
>
> [INFO]  socket.io started
>
> [ERROR] Error occurred. TypeError: Cannot call method 'init' of undefined
>       at Object.start (/app.js:8:7)

app.js listing:

```
var ACS = require('acs').ACS,
    logger = require('acs').logger,
    express = require('express'),
    partials = require('express-partials');

// initialize app (setup ACS library and logger)
function start(app) {
  ACS.init('***', '***');
  logger.setLevel('DEBUG');

  //use connect.session
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ key: 'node.acs', secret: "secret" }));

  //set favicon
  app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/images/favicon.ico'));

  //set to use express-partial for view
  app.use(partials());

  //Request body parsing middleware supporting JSON, urlencoded, and multipart
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
}

// release resources
function stop() {

}
```

Ofcourse I have my OATH key and secret at the ***. Same when running from command line (acs run).

I am running Titanium Studio, build 3.4.1.201410281727.

I can however publish the service, and then run it from the cloud without any issues. For development this is not ideal, so want to run it locally (local node.ACS server).

I guess there must be something wrong with where things are installed (only used default), or permissions. Anyone that got a clue how to fix this? Have spent some hours now searching the internet, but seem to be the only one with this exact problem. No clue what else to try.
Thanks for reading this far. If you require more information to help me, let me know.

Comment: Same problem here, a project that was working well two months ago, without any change, now is not working (same errors than you). The only thing I remember that changed was an upgrade from 3.4GA to 3.5GA. Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the problem. They changed the way to use ACS in the last upgrade.

Classic mode was:

```
var ACS = require('acs').ACS;
ACS.init('<ACS Key>', '<ACS secret');
```

Now they changed it and ACS is a "module", like any other one, so you must use the new way. In the package.json file add it as a dependecy:

```
"dependencies": {
    "acs-node": ">=0.9.2"
}
```

Install it: `npm install acs-node`

Now you can use it in its new format, on the app.js file:

```
var ACS = require('acs-node');
ACS.init('<App Key>');
```

It's all explained here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/guide/node_acs